# Lost mouseover when mouse is over inner element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have example like below. How to avoid "lost of mouseover" on `<div>` when mouse is over inner `<span>` ?

```
<div id="box">
  ABC
  <span style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;">abc</span>
</div>
```

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PjhmC/).

Comment: Use mouseonter() and mouseleave().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jquery hover instead of mouseenter/mouseout e.g.

```
$('#box').hover(function(){
   //Enter code
},
function(){
   //Exit code
});
```

As another user mentions, you could use a chained event of mousenter and mouse leave e.g.

```
$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

However, hover is simply shorthand for the above.

Answer (score 4):

Switch to `mouseenter` & `mouseleave`; http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/PjhmC/3/

> The [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event differs from mouseover in the way it handles
>   event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the
>   mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered